# How can I install OpenJDK7 32 bit (JDK, not just JRE) on my CentOS7 64 bit system?

Tags: java, centos, java-7

How can I install OpenJDK7 32 bit (JDK, not just JRE) on my CentOS7 64 bit system?

I can't seem to find any useful information for this. Most of the websites talk about installation of JDK8 and above and none of them talk about installing a 32 bit JDK/JRE.

If I run `yum search java | grep openjdk`, for 1.7 these are the options I get:

```
java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64 : OpenJDK Runtime Environment
java-1.7.0-openjdk-accessibility.x86_64 : OpenJDK accessibility connector
java-1.7.0-openjdk-demo.x86_64 : OpenJDK Demos
java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64 : OpenJDK Development Environment
java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless.x86_64 : The OpenJDK runtime environment without
java-1.7.0-openjdk-javadoc.noarch : OpenJDK API Documentation
java-1.7.0-openjdk-src.x86_64 : OpenJDK Source Bundle
```

Comment: java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64 should be the jdk

Comment: No, I installed it - it's the 64 bit JVM - `java version "1.7.0_261"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.6.22.2.el7_8-x86_64 u261-b02)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.261-b02, mixed mode)`

Comment: Right, I misunderstood your question